# Stack of VM reverse traversal: reaching host port from a Docker container within a Vagrant machine

Tags: docker, vagrant

We are implementing a CI infrastructure as Docker containers.

Development of the solution takes place on OS X machines:

1. The OS X physical machine (*Host*) has Vagrant installed on it, plus a service listening on **localhost:2200**.
2. On *Host*, we `vagrant up` a Linux machine (*VM-a*) on which we provision Docker.
3. On *VM-a*, we `docker run` a Linux container (*VM-b*). *VM-b* needs to interact with the service running on *Host*.

By way of well-documented port binding, we are able to reach any listening port on both *VM-a* and *VM-b* from the *Host*.

Yet, we cannot identify a way to have *VM-b* reach *Host* port **2200** on *Host*'s **localhost** interface.

Is it possible to achieve such communication? 
If so, how?

Comment: it's not necessary to provision docker on linux machine. vagrant has docker provider, which allow to run docker containers directly https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/docker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we found the "magic" interface on which to reach the *Host* from any VM, i.e. from booth *VM-a* and *VM-b* (nested in *VM-a*).

It is `10.0.2.2`.

Comment: Glad you took the time to write your answer for the community :) Cheers.. 

I want to ask, out of curiosity, can't you use machine hostnames?

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş I don't think you can *by default*. But you probably can configure your VM name resolution to associate whichever name you want to the IP above.